# Add Multiple Values with .each()

Tags: javascript, each

I'm trying to use .each() to run through the DOM and create multiple variables based on the height of a certain set of elements. Let's say the width of all the images in a list.

In this simplified example, I want to add width to each list item in an unordered list based on the width of the image that the list item holds. This way the width of the list item will equal the width of the image inside.

**HTML**

```
 <ul>
  <li><img src="image_01.jpg" width="100" /></li>
  <li><img src="image_02.jpg" width="60" /></li>
  <li><img src="image_03.jpg" width="220" /></li>
  <li><img src="image_04.jpg" width="40" /></li>
</ul>
```

**JQUERY**

```
var itemWidth = 0;
$('ul li img').each(function () {
    var tmpWidth = $(this).width(); 

    if (tmpWidth > itemWidth) {
        itemWidth = (tmpWidth);
        elemWidth = $('ul li').width();
        $('ul li').css( "width", itemWidth );

    }
});
```

Right now it is setting the width of each list item BUT it's setting them all equal to the largest image in the list rather than setting each list item with a different width based on the image within.

Do I need to make a for loop with an array to hold the multiple variables respective to each width?

here's an example on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EBMM2/

Comment: check with the script
http://jsfiddle.net/btYkH/

Comment: Please check your question before submitting it, it's hard to type an answer when you change it during that time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to change, starting from the img, is the enclosing `li` element. You can get it with `$(this).closest('li')`.

Change

```
var tmpWidth = $(this).width(); 
if (tmpWidth > itemWidth) {
    itemWidth = (tmpWidth);
    elemWidth = $('ul li').width();
    $('ul li').css( "width", itemWidth );
}
```

to

```
var imgWidth = $(this).width();
var elem = $(this).closest('li');
if (imgWidth>elem.width()) {
    elem.css("width", imgWidth);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GqEvz/1/)

Do it like this >>

```
$('ul li img').each(function () {
    var itemWidth = $(this).width(); 
    $(this).parent().css( "width", itemWidth );
});
```

When you were making it this way `$('ul li').css( "width", itemWidth );` you are setting all `li`'s width together in this piece of code, change it to `$(this).parent().css( "width", itemWidth );` and it'll work fine.

Answer (score 0):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/3uPud/)***

What you need to do is reference the parent node instead of every element when you are checking the width of the image. You also do not need to use a variable to conditionally apply this, just do it to every item

```
$('ul li img').each(function () {
 var itemWidth = $(this).width();
 $(this.parentNode).css( "width", itemWidth );
});
```